# how to select random samples of elements with a particular id

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select 5 review ids for each business from a dataframe with reviews ids and business ids. I thought it would iterate over the groupby object, but this does not work.

```
df_b = df.groupby('business_id')
selected = random.sample(df_b,5).review_ids
```

Comment: You may want to give an example data frame, show the output you desire and explain how your code does not meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure a `DataFrameGroupBy` object is what you want. I think you'd be better off using `DataFrame.sample()` for each id.

```
frames = list()
for buisness_id in df['business_id'].unique():
    frame = df[df['business_id'] == business_id].sample(5)
    frames.append(frame)

df = pd.concat(frames)
```